# Как через python авторизоваться на госуслугах?

Tags: python

Есть база, которую необходимо проверить на валидность, но какой запрос get-ом не шлешь, все равно пишет статус 200, не понимаю, почему и где может быть ошибка (проверил лично на своем кабинете, даже когда не правильный пароль ввожу, пишет 200 : OK)
Если пишу post-ом то пишет 405
код:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/login/'
r=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('тут логин', 'тут пароль'))
print(r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

как пример

```
import requests

json_data = {
    'login': '+7(905)4443311',# по почте 'grut@mail.ru'
    'idType': 'phone',        # по почте 'email'
    'password': '4567890',
}

response = requests.post('https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/api/login', json=json_data)
if response.json()['status'] == 'error':
    print('Неверные логин или пароль')
```

может потребоватся cookies, headers. Рекомендую вам делать регистрацию и последующие запросы делать в одной сессии.
status_code == 200 Означает что пришел ответ от сервера куда посылался запрос. Сам ответ будет в response.json().

Comment: simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) - выдает такую ошибку

Comment: @МихаилДужарь это пример правельного запроса,  добавте в ваш код cookies, headers.

Comment: куки нет возможности поставить, так как нужно залогинить и разлогинить много пользователей

Comment: Для этого нужно заходить в сессий с разных браузеров(прописывается в headers). Возможно через прокси, но это проверять надо.

Answer (score 0):

[image: гос]ваш код работает так как и должен работать, вы проверяете статус, в последней строке.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/login/'
r=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('тут логин', 'тут пароль'))
=> print(r.status_code)
```

Пожалуйста поясните, что именно вам нужно сделать

Comment: Необходимо залогиниться на госуслугах, если авторизация прошла успешно - то вывести что все ок, если нет то "не ок" , просто я так понял, что авторизация не проходит

Comment: @МихаилДужарь Понятно, тогда вам нужно добавить условие, if r.status_code == 200:    print("Успешно!") также и для иначе...

Comment: авторизация не проходит , но почему-то выдает 200 , что все ок, пытался зайти сам под тем логином и паролем - не получилось

Comment: @МихаилДужарь Если вы сами не смогли зайти с логином и паролем на сайте(без кода) значит ваш логин и пароль, которые вы вводите неправильны

Comment: Да, но при таком случае не должно выводиться 200, верно?Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть авторизация не проходит и в моем коде что-то не так?

Comment: @МихаилДужарь Да верно, значит ошибка в коде

Comment: Тогда подскажите пожалуйста, или укажите, что не так в коде, и почему может не проходить авторизация

Comment: @МихаилДужарь если честно, я не все понимаю в вашем коде, так как мало работал с запросами, но мне кажется нужно отправлять post запрос, заполняя данные, но лучше посмотреть документацию

Comment: пост запрос выдает ошибку 405 Response ,даже при правильном логином и паролем

Comment: @МихаилДужарь в таком случае, ошибка в авторизации(в коде), советую найти в документации, то как авторизоваться

Comment: Искал, применял, не помогло, решил задать вопрос

Comment: @МихаилДужарь если хотите, поищу ответ

Comment: Если у вас получится найти что-то новое, то я буду очень признателен

Comment: @МихаилДужарь мне кажется мой код будет работать, вот: `s = requests.Session()
data = {"login_username":"my_login", "login_password":"my_password"}
url = "сайт"
r = s.post(url, data=data)` <br>советую попробовать

Comment: Не работает, 405 Response снова

Comment: @МихаилДужарь пожалуйста покажите свой код

Comment: `import requests
s = requests.Session()
data = {"login":"login", "password":"passw"}
url = "https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/login/"
r = s.post(url, data=data)
print(r.status_code)`

Comment: Я прикрепил скриншот к моему ответу, возможно вам следует подождать пока на сайте пройдут профилактические работы...

Comment: сервис авторизаций -работает